# Call to a member function notify() on null in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to send an SMS to a mobile phone (if he had already turned on the two-factor authentication system).

So at `LoginController` I added this method:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return $this->loggendin($request , $user);
}
```

And this `loggendin` method is inside of a trait called `TwoFactorAuthentication`, which goes like this:

```
trait TwoFactorAuthenticate
{
    public function loggendin(Request $request , $user)
    {
        if($user->hasTwoFactorAuthenticatedEnabled()) {
            auth()->logout();

            $request->session()->flash('auth' , [
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'using_sms' => false,
                'remember' => $request->has('remember')
            ]);


            if($user->two_factor_type == 'sms') {
                $code = ActiveCode::generateCode($user);
                // Todo Send Sms
                $request->user()->notify(new ActiveCodeNotification($code , $user->phone_number));

                $request->session()->push('auth.using_sms' , true);
            }

            return redirect(route('twofa.token'));
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when I want to log in, this message appears on the screen which is saying:

> **Error** Call to a member function notify() on null

Which is referring to this line:

```
$request->user()->notify(new ActiveCodeNotification($code , $user->phone_number));
```

And this `ActiveCodeNotification` holds some settings for sending the SMS.

If you would like to visit that, here it is:

```
class ActiveCodeNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $code;

    public $phoneNumber;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($code , $phoneNumber)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
        $this->phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [GhasedakChannel::class];
    }


    public function toGhasedakSms($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'text' => "{$this->code}",
            'number' => $this->phoneNumber
        ];
    }
}
```

So what's going wrong here that I get Call to a member function notify() on null while it's two parameters have value.

So if you know, please let me know. I would really appreciate any idea from you guys...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

First, make sure your User model has the Notifiable trait.

Top of the User Model class:

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
```

After that:

```
class User extends Model{
use Notifiable; // ....
```

And then...

Instead of

```
$request->user()->notify(new ActiveCodeNotification($code , $user->phone_number));
```

Use this

```
$user->notify(new ActiveCodeNotification($code, $user->phone_number));
```

Or

Before calling auth()->logout();

use it at first:

```
auth()->user()->notify(new ActiveCodeNotification($code, $user->phone_number));
```

then, you can call auth()->logout();

Worked for me recently

Answer (score 0):

The `$request->user()` would be `null` at that point on `LoginController` because the request was not authenticated and the user is not set on the request instance yet.

You have to use the `$user` argument instead:

```
$user->notify(new ActiveCodeNotification($code , $user->phone_number));
```

Note: make sure that your `User` model has `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` trait in order to be able to use `notify()`.